# VPN connectivity in iPhone Simulator

Tags: ios5, ios-simulator, html, vpn

Currently I'm accessing a webpage from VPN network. My MAC machine is connected to a VPN network that way i can access a webpage hosted on remote system. Safari browser in MAC OS X opens the page properly but I want to load the page in iPad 2(ios v5.0) SIMULATOR browser. So i created a new Xcode project and run the simulator, open browser and hit the webpage. Its not working

Webpage loading with MAC Safari browser but not with simulator browser. how to load the page in simulator browser???

Comment: I'm also experiencing problems with VPN in the iOS simulator.  Won't connect to a remote address (starting iOS 8), whereas before it was no problem.

Answer (score 11):

If you connect to the VPN after booting the simulated device, you will need to reboot the simulated device.  The iOS 8 simulator runtime has a known bug whereby it does not properly respond to network configuration changes.  Please file radars at http://bugreport.apple.com if this impacts you severely to "upvote" the existing radar with a dupe.

Answer (score 7):

I believe I found the solution to this problem.  I've seen it on iOS 8.  Anyway, the OSX Firewall is not allowing connections to the iOS Simulator.

The way I fixed it was with an open iOS Simulator, in the dock I right clicked on it and under Options I clicked Show in Finder.  You'll notice that the iOS Simulator.app is inside the Xcode.app bundle.  Keep this Finder window open, you will need it.

Now go into System Preferences > Security and Privacy > Firewall.  Click the lock to make changes and enter your password.  Hit Firewall Options...  Now it will show a list of apps that are allowed to accept incoming connections.  You'll see that if you click the + button, you will not be able to go deeper into the Xcode.app's package contents.

Now using the Finder window from before, drag and drop iOS Simulator.app into this list.

You may need to restart the iOS simulator.  Not sure.  But that fixed it for me.

Comment: Restart the iOS simulator at the end and Poof! it works like a charm

Comment: Restart the simulator with the mac connected to the VPN and works